# Vertical Align an element in CSS

Tags: html, css

Dear experts, I was trying to align an paragraph to the middle of an division element via CSS and I somehow can't get it to work.

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .wrap{
background:red;
height: 5em;  
     }
     p{
     background:blue; 
        height: 2em; 
vertical-align:middle; 

      }
  </style>


<div class="wrap">
    <p>
    ALIGN TEXT
    </p>
</div>
```

It doesn't work in IE nor firefox,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a nice hackish example](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html), i'd put the IE css in conditionals instead of hiding it with hacks, other that that nice.

```
  <div style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align
"*Applies to: inline-level and 'table-cell' elements*"

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: but <p> is not an inline element though

Comment: Exactly, it's block, so the *vertical-align* property does not apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `vertical-align:middle`, `display:inline-block`, and an empty inline element with 100% height:

http://jsfiddle.net/HVtuD/
​

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='text'>vertical-align + inline-block<br>trick<br>in action</div>
</div>

#container{
  height: 300px;border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;
}
#text,#container:before{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
  #container:before{
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's impossible to vertically align anything without it being a table, or without using Javascript.

Comment: This is one of those classic areas where teaching someone that is used to using tables for layout to start using CSS hits a giant and horrible train wreck.  CSS is powerful, but it's warts are glaring and it's idiosyncrasies are legion.